# Get a sum of CPU usage of all child threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-core

I have a console application which spins up multiple tasks at startup.
Further each of these tasks have timers that do various async operations (db reads/writes).

I would like to calculate the CPU usage for each of these startup tasks (should include the sum of usages of the child tasks initiated by them) and log it periodically.

I already checked [Get Thread Cpu Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201021/get-thread-cpu-usage) and [How to get the CPU Usage in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c) But these seem to be either for a single thread or the entire process.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Could you include an example of a parent task, so that we can see how the timers are used to start the child asynchronous operations?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I have an interface with a method like `StartProcessing`. This interface is implemented by many classes.
At the startup I get the instances of all these classes using DI.
Then I'm using `Task.Run(() => someInstance.StartProcessing())` inside a `foreach`.

Each of these classes have a `System.Timers.Timer` inside them which performs db (and more) operations on regular intervals.

Comment: I see. I was going to suggest a custom `TaskScheduler` for accumulating the duration of (hopefully) CPU-bound operations, but since you are scheduling the child tasks on the `ThreadPool` (this is what the `Task.Run` and `System.Timers.Timer` does), my suggestion is not applicable.

Comment: You could measure the time yourself with a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch and then calculate the time of each operation using the whole process CPU time.

Comment: @sneusse, that would miss information about fire and forget tasks. There are also multiple 3rd party calls / cloud services getting used. I was hoping for a way to avoid manual diagnostic code for each small operation.